# Connect Function App To A Specific Device?

Tags: azure, function, iot

Is there a way to connect an Azure Function App to a specific device?

I have two devices and when I read from the IOTHub I get the messages from both devices but I only want to see results from the one device. Is there a way to connect only to the one device?

I am using C# in Visual studio and I have the IOTTriggerHUB. I have tried for hours and can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

This should be achievable, because you can filter the deviceId with Azure function,

If you are using C#,

You can get device ID from SystemProperties:

```
public static async Task Run(EventData myIoTHubMessage1, TraceWriter log)
{
    var deviceId = myIoTHubMessage1.SystemProperties["iothub-connection-device-id"];       
}
```

In JavaScript, you can use the following method to get the device id:

```
context.bindingData.systemProperties["iothub-connection-device-id"]
```